# Как проверить наследуемый тип с параметром T?

Tags: c#, ооп

Погуглил, но ответа не нашёл, скорее всего я неправильно ставлю вопрос!

Пример кода:

```
public class Base {}
public class Base<T> {}
public class Base<T, E> {}

public class Test1 : Base<int> {}
public class Test2 : Base<string, int> {}

// Do<Test1>(); <- чтобы можно было такое выполнить
// Do<Test2>(); <- и такое


public void Do<T>() where T : Base, Base<_>, Base<_, _>
{
    // some govnocode
}
```

Собственно вопрос: Реально ли в c# сделать такую проверку типа как в этом методе, не учитывая передаваемый в дженерик тип данных? То-есть, нужно чтобы классы наследуемые от Base, Base подходили к данному методу.
Есть вариант сделать общий интерфейс, например, и все такое... но мне интересен именно такой вариант как в коде выше.

Comment: на данный момент ограничения на generic объединяются через `И` а не `ИЛИ`, поэтому в таком виде сделать нельзя.

Comment: Слишком абстрактный вопрос. Чтобы решить задачу,гадо понять что именно требуется. Так как вы предложили - не получится сделать.

Comment: Окей, а если использовать только один тип, но чтобы был конракт, что необходимо 2 параметра, то-есть передаваемый тип должен наследоваться от Base<1, 2> с любыми типами данных. То-есть как проверить от какого базового класса наследуется тип?

Comment: Указать в ограничении базовый класс или интерфейс. Например у классов могут быть разные базовые классы, но общий интерфейс, в котором есть нужный метод.